# i want below code to print for reverse way like 10 to 0

Tags: javascript

```js
for (let i =  1; i <=  10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(i) }, (i * 1000) )
}
```

```
for (let i =  1; i <=  10; i++) {
setTimeout(() => { console.log(i) }, (i * 1000) )
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Try: `for (let i = 10; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: I'm convinced something like this has already been asked before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this?

```
for (let i =  10; i >=  1; i--)
```

or this:

```
for (let i =  1; i <=  10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(10-i) }, (i * 1000) )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Rick, your code is working very good. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
for (let i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), (10 - i) * 1000)
}
```

And here a more functional solution:

```js
const logReversedNumbers = (n, ms) => Array.from(
  { length: n + 1 }, (_, i) => setTimeout(() => console.log(i), (n - i) * ms)
)

logReversedNumbers(10, 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Yosvel Quintero, your code is working very good. Thnk you again

Answer (score 1):

you can just do this

```js
for (let i =  0; i <  10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(10 - i) }, (i * 1000) )
}
```

Comment: Thank you  very very much R4ncid, 
your code is working very good.
Thnk you again